# How to find an object from a List of objects?

Tags: c#

I got a list of columns in the variable ParentColumnNames, i need to find a single Column object within this list using the selectedvalue of another combobox. How can i get that? Please help...

```
List<Columns> ParentColumnNames = new List<Columns>();
     ParentColumnNames = metadataobj.GetColumns(cbParentTable.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

within this i need to find single object using cbParentColumn.SelectedValue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ParentColumnNames.Where(x => x.Name == cbParentColumn.SelectedValue).FirstOrDefault();
```

My answer assumes that the `Columns` class has a property `Name` and that this property contains the value you are looking for.